# Geoserver HTTP ERROR 500 on layer preview

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geonode

I have followed the installation instructions on the official Geonode page to install it on ubuntu(18.04.4) and when I finish it I have published a Layer but when I click on Openlayers preview of the Geoserver layer,it viewed with this error:

[image]

---

[image]

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /geoserver/geonode/wms. Reason:
>
> ```
> Server Error
> ```
>
> Caused by:
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment   at
>   org.geoserver.monitor.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:193)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   ...

---

I don't know what is the problem, it must be from Geoserver because I already used the layer on another computer with Geoserver and it works perfectly.

The bottom of the error log is:

> Caused by:
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)  at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
>     at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
>     at
>   java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1181)
>     at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1170)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.wms.WMSServiceExceptionHandler.handleImageException(WMSServiceExceptionHandler.java:214)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.wms.WMSServiceExceptionHandler.handleServiceException(WMSServiceExceptionHandler.java:147)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleServiceException(Dispatcher.java:1799)
>     at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.exception(Dispatcher.java:1746)     at
>   org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.flow.controller.IpBlacklistFilter.doFilter(IpBlacklistFilter.java:89)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.monitor.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:140)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.oauth2.GeoServerOAuthAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerOAuthAuthenticationFilter.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1629)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

And My console have these error:

[image]

Comment: We need to know how you added the layer, what sort of layer it is and the bottom of the error log.

Comment: I have edited the question by adding the end of the error log and the layer has been added from a shapefile!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a headless system, one without a GUI running. In that setup, you need to pass the following system variable to the JVM running GeoServer:

`-Djava.awt.headless=true`

Comment: I don't know where put it, I start geonode with paver start if it's any help!!

Comment: @pablovilla: `-Djava.awt.headless=true` is set in `startup.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I run into a very similar but bit different error ([`-Djava.awt.headless=true` was set correctly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/353047/97303) already in `startup.sh`) with GeoServer 2.20.1 on MacOS 12.1:

```
geoserver HTTP ERROR 500
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.java2d.SurfaceData
```

Finally, I could trace it back on the wrong JRE: although v11 was installed as well, GeoServer fell back on the most recent version (v17, in this case). So the solution: make sure GeoServer uses the correct Java version. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by using wrong jdk version. Use version 11.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and were able to solve it following the instructions on this [geoserver page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/linuxscript.html)

- First, create the file `/etc/init.d/geoserver` and copy the content from [this file](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/_downloads/5c56ec58bc153d3a7dd6ef198f9eeaf7/geoserver_deb)
  and paste the content into it, then change the user mode .

  ```
  sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/geoserver
  ```
- Second, create the file `etc/default/geoserver` and paste the following lines into it.

  ```
  USER=<user>
  GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir
  GEOSERVER_HOME=/usr/share/geoserver
  JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
  JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
  ```
- change the `<user>` with your user name and the OpenJDK with the name of the version you installed.
- then to start/check status of geoserver:

  ```
  sudo systemctl start geoserver
  sudo systemctl status geoserver
  ```
- to stop geoserver:

  ```
  sudo systemctl stop geoserver
  ```

Now, when you open the tiger-ny openlayer in the geoserver Layer preview

[image: OpenLayer preview]

Comment: did not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and select a JDK which is compatible with geoserver, that is versions 11 or 17. You might have to install one of those if you don't have them already.

I had the same problem. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by uninstalling it and installing it again, but this time I used Java11, and not Java17 as previously.

Answer (score 0):

USE java version 11
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/
i used 21 and 17 but it didnt wroked well. then i tired version 11 . it worked well