# Layer Preview not working at all on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I recently installed GeoServer on  an Arch Linux system from the arch user repository. Sadly I cant preview the layers at all. When I try to preview the layer using the OpenLayers option it just shows a blank map like this:

[image]

The error I am getting  after I click in the blank space is this:

```
Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.java2d.SurfaceData
    at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:133)
    at java.desktop/sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:73)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1182)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1170)
    at org.geoserver.wms.WMSServiceExceptionHandler.handleImageException(WMSServiceExceptionHandler.java:214)
    at org.geoserver.wms.WMSServiceExceptionHandler.handleServiceException(WMSServiceExceptionHandler.java:147)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleServiceException(Dispatcher.java:1799)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.exception(Dispatcher.java:1746)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:275)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
```

Comment: What is your Java version? Geoserver supports versions 8 and 11.

Comment: It's 11. I have tried it with both the versions 8 and 11. The problem still persists

Comment: The click on the map test may not reveal the real error that has happened earlier. The map should not be empty. Increase the logging level of GeoServer into GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING and restart the service. Hopefully you will get errors into the log. Does other things work, for example the service GetCapabilities? Can you use the WMS with QGIS?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I can only get WFS service to show visually. I'm able to get WMS capabilities but, nothing draws and no ability to view layer preview.
If I use java 8 1.8.0_202 or above (including java 11) I have these problems. If I use java 8 1.8.0_181 or below it works. Yet, GeoServer indicates java 11 works...

Comment: I had the same problem, but with a [different error message](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421632/97303). And the problem was indeed that GeoServer used the wrong Java version.

Answer (score 4):

I installed GeoServer with jre 17 on Ubuntu Linux an had the same problem. The tip with setting path and `JAVA_HOME` didn't solve the problem, but the following advice helped:

```
rm webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/marlin-0.9.3.jar
```

See: [Geoserver - Java Considerations](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#production-java)

Answer (score 0):

After the correct configuration of `JAVA_HOME` and `Path` variables, with IDK 8 directions :

1. `path= %JAVA_HOME%\bin;`
2. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321`

and, after the reboot of the PC, the Layer Preview function in Geoserver has started working again.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when GeoServer is used on a headless machine (no GUI) without telling Java that's the case. Add the following to the command line starting Java (the exact position depends on the container):

`-Djava.awt.headless=true`